# print in the same line with comma in python 2.6

Tags: python, printing

I'm using python 2.6. I have a variable "host" which stores a list of my server names. I want to print them as comma separated values in the same line

print host

```html
xxxxxx.es.ad.com
xxxxxx.es.ad.com
xxxxxx.es.ad.com
```

i want to print them as xxxxxx.es.ad.com,xxxxxx.es.ad.com,xxxxxx.es.ad.com,

i tried using end and sep but it says invalid syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `host` is a string with linebreaks, this is a trivial `split` + `join` operation:

```
>>> host = 'a\nb\nc'
>>> ','.join(host.split())
'a,b,c'
```

If you are guaranteed to only have one line-break between each host and are worried about other whitespace in the host names themselves (which there shouldn't be), use `split('\n')`.

Answer (score 0):

```
host = ['xxxxxx.es.ad.com','xxxxxx.es.ad.com','xxxxxx.es.ad.com']

print(','.join(host))
#prints >> xxxxxx.es.ad.com,xxxxxx.es.ad.com,xxxxxx.es.ad.com
```

I'm guessing you have a list of strings?